# Unresolved external symbol error when using CMake in Visual Studio 2017 to build a wxWidgets project

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, wxwidgets

I'm working on a CMake project in Visual Studio 2017 that targets wxWidgets 3.1.0.  Whenever I try to build it, I get numerous error messages similar to the following:

```
unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual class wxRefCounter * __cdecl wxObject::CreateRefData(void)const " (?CreateRefData@wxObject@@MEBAPEAVwxRefCounter@@XZ)
```

Here is the content of my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project (FNDice-cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)
set(wxWidgets_ROOT_DIR C:/wxWidgets-3.1.0)
find_package(wxWidgets REQUIRED all)
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
add_executable(FNDice-cmake WIN32 FNDiceApp.h FNDiceApp.cpp MainWindow.h MainWindow.cpp FNDie.h FNDie.cpp AboutDialog.h AboutDialog.cpp FNDice.rc fndice-small.ico wxIconBundleResLoader.h wxIconBundleResLoader.cpp sqlite3.c sqlite3.h LICENSE-2.0.h about24.h help24.h history24.h new24.h open24.h save24.h)
target_link_libraries(FNDice-cmake ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

I did find a similar question ([linker error using wxwidgets with cmake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3747099/linker-error-using-wxwidgets-with-cmake)), but as you can see, I'm already using `WIN32` in my `add_executable()` line.

Comment: what happen if you just try to build the project inside MSVC?

Comment: If you mean by creating a regular Win32 C++ project in Visual Studio, I've done that without any problems.  However, I wanted to use CMake.

Comment: and the purpose of that? wxWidgets is not yet CMake friendly. There is an effort to make it as such and some people are even succeeded but AFAIK on *nix/Mac only.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem:
The wxWidgets website does not seem to list CMake as a method for building wxWidgets projects, but CMake has a documented findpackage method for wxWidgets, and, following the instructions for that package:

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project (wxHello)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
set(wxWidgets_CONFIGURATION mswu)
find_package(wxWidgets COMPONENTS core base REQUIRED)
if (NOT wxWidgets_FOUND)
    message(SEND_ERROR "wxWidgets_FOUND => ${wxWidgets_FOUND}")
endif ()
include(${wxWidgets_USE_FILE})
message ( "wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS => ${wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
set_property( DIRECTORY PROPERTY VS_STARTUP_PROJECT "${PROJECT_NAME}" )
# add_executable(test ${SOURCES})
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} app.cpp app.h frame.cpp frame.h stdafx.h)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${wxWidgets_LIBRARIES})
```

The generated Makefile and visual studio solution file fail with a linking error.

I can manually build the program from the command line, and this works fine, but the whole reason for using wxWidgets is portability, and command line building is not portable.

```
CL.exe /c /ZI /I%VCINCLUDE% /I%WXWIN%\lib\vc_x64_lib\mswud /JMC /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:classic /sdl /Od /D _DEBUG /D _WINDOWS /D _UNICODE /D UNICODE /Gm- /EHsc /RTC1 /MDd /GS /fp:precise /permissive- /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /std:c++17  /Gd /TP /FC /errorReport:prompt ..\*.cpp

link /LIBPATH:%WXWIN%\lib\vc_x64_lib   *.obj kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib Comctl32.lib Rpcrt4.lib
```

program built in the command line works fine, or built with with a visual studio *.sln file works fine - just the Makefile and the sln file built by CMake fails.